# Combinations of Characters in an n by n Character Array:

Tags: arrays, matrix, graph-theory, combinatorics

First a note: Sorry that my images aren't separated. I'm a new member, so I don't have enough reputation points to post more than a single hyperlink.

Let M be an n by n array (mathematically square matrix) of characters.

In M, I need to be able to find all permutation of characters with a restriction. The permutations do not have to be linear, but they they **must** contain characters such that each character is adjacent to at least one other character in the permutation. An example of an acceptable permutation follows below:

An unacceptable permutation is shown below.

I have derived this much:

- A permutation can have at most n squared characters in it (as no characters can be repeated).
- I do not know the exact number of permutation given the restrictions, but I believe there can be no more than the value generated by evaluating the expression pictured in the hyperlink.

I can very easily find the permutations which only contain characters in straight lines: vertical lines, horizontal lines, and diagonals. I am not sure of a way to exhaustively find all remaining permutations.

I have done research and have not been able to find a solution to a similar problem.

Any advice in the development of such an exhaustive algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDNfv.png

Comment: Is a "combination" an ordered sequence of elements in the matrix, or is it merely a set of elements from the matrix?

Comment: Excuse me. I meant **permutations**. Order DOES differentiate the following from each other: {A,B,C,D} is not equal to {D,C,B,A}.

Comment: hopefully those edits meet with your approval. I bought the image onsite (or at least to the "prefferred" provider) and edited tour text to remove the apology (that didn't really apply any more). Let me know if I've stuffed up the core of your question and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: Oops. It looks like when I went back and edited it again to read **permutations** instead of **combinations** I wasn't allowed to save the changes you made since I'm still a new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One algorithm comes to mind immediately, though optimizations can be made, if time-complexity is a concern.

At each element in the 2x2 array (or we can call it a matrix if you like), there are 8 directions that we can travel (North, NE, East, SE, South, SW, West, NW).

The pseudo code for the meat of the algorithm goes a bit like this (I assume pass by value, so that "current_string" is a new string at each function call):

```
find(position, direction, current_string){
    new_letter = m[0, position + direction];
    if(!current_string.Contains(new_letter)){
        // We have not yet encountered this letter during the search.
        // If letters occur more than once in the array, then you must
        // assign an index to each position in the array instead and
        // store which positions have been encountered along each
        // search path instead.
        current_string += new_letter;
        find(position, (0, 1), current_string);
        find(position, (1, 1), current_string);
        find(position, (1, 0), current_string);
        find(position, (1, -1), current_string);
        find(position, (0, -1), current_string);
        find(position, (-1, -1), current_string);
        find(position, (-1, 0), current_string);
        find(position, (-1, 1), current_string);
    } else {
        // This letter has been encountered during this path search,
        // terminate this path search. See comment above if letters
        // occur more than once in the matrix.
        print current_string; // Print one of the found strings!
    }
}
```

Now you need to add some checks for things like "is position + direction outside the bounds of the array, if so, print current_string and terminate".

The high level idea of the algorithm above is to search along all possible paths recursively, terminating paths when they run into themselves (in the same way that snakes die in the game [Snake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game%29)).

If you use hashing to test containment of a new letter against the current string (as per the line `if(!current_string.Contains(new_letter)){`), which is amortized O(1) searching, then the worst case runtime complexity of this algorithm is linear in the number of possible strings there are in the matrix. I.e. if there are n possible string combonations in the matrix, then this algorithm takes about cn steps to complete for large n, where c is some constant.